# How to take an average /sum of (5D tensor) sequence of images? becomes 4D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, transform, tensor

I have a 5D sequence of images from feature extraction module (None, 4, 10, 4, 1536), but I need to take average/sum among all sequence features so that can fit to 2DCNN layer (4D tensor), how to do that specifically in TensorFlow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor, axis=-1)`

Comment: Thankyou!! one more question i wanna try to concate it with another 4d layer ,and the result shape from reduce_mean is not match
 A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 4, 10, 64), (None, 10, 4, 64)]
How to reorder the values inside the tensor?

Comment: use `tf.transpose()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce_mean()`:

```
tf.math.reduce_mean(input_tensor, axis=-1)
```